# How to count repeated objects attributes?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, oop, python-itertools

I have next code and I create objects for every entry pet:

```
from itertools import groupby
class Petshop():
    def __init__(self, entryDate, name, ownerName):
        self.entryDate = entryDate
        self.name = name
        self.ownerName = ownerName

class Pets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.petsList = []
    
    def addPets(self, entryDate, name, ownerName):
        entry_pet = Petshop(entryDate, name, ownerName)
        self.petsList.append(entry_pet)
    
    def printPets(self):
        self.petsList.sort(key=lambda p: p.entryDate)
        counter = 0
        for group in groupby(self.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
            ls = list(group)
            print("---------------", ls[0], '------------------')
            for pet in list(ls[1]):
                print("Name:", pet.name)
                print("Owner name:", pet.ownerName)
                if pet.name in list(ls[1]):
                    counter += 1
                print('There are ',counter,'pets with the same name')

pet = Pets()

pet.addPets('04/13/2021','Pinky', 'David Smith')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Charlie', 'Joe Davis')
pet.addPets('04/13/2021','Pinky', 'Daniel Trincot')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'Susan Jones')
pet.addPets('12/22/2018', 'Teddy', 'Carl Johnson')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'Richard Campbell')
pet.addPets('04/13/2021','Max', 'Bryan Miller')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Buddy', 'Kathy Brown')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'John Brown')
pet.printPets()
```

With that code I would like to count how many repeated pets entry by date, so for example I expect in console:

```
--------------- 04/13/2021 ------------------
Name: Pinky
Owner name: David Smith
Name: Pinky
Owner name: Daniel Trincot
Name: Max
Owner name: Bryan Miller
There are 2 pets with the same name
--------------- 07/10/2020 ------------------
Name: Charlie
Owner name: Joe Davis
Name: Kenny
Owner name: Susan Jones
Name: Kenny
Owner name: Richard Campbell
Name: Buddy
Owner name: Kathy Brown
Name: Kenny
Owner name: John Brown
There are 3 pets with the same name
--------------- 12/22/2018 ------------------
Name: Teddy
Owner name: Carl Johnson
There are 0 pets with the same name
```

I tried to do that with:

```
if pet.name in list(ls[1]):
     counter += 1
```

But that does not work, because I think my code does not get into the if and I just get in console:

```
--------------- 04/13/2021 ------------------
Name: Pinky
Owner name: David Smith
There are  0 pets with the same name
Name: Pinky
Owner name: Daniel Trincot
There are  0 pets with the same name
Name: Max
Owner name: Bryan Miller
There are  0 pets with the same name
--------------- 07/10/2020 ------------------
Name: Charlie
Owner name: Joe Davis
There are  0 pets with the same name
Name: Kenny
Owner name: Susan Jones
There are  0 pets with the same name
Name: Kenny
Owner name: Richard Campbell
There are  0 pets with the same name
Name: Buddy
Owner name: Kathy Brown
There are  0 pets with the same name
Name: Kenny
Owner name: John Brown
There are  0 pets with the same name
--------------- 12/22/2018 ------------------
Name: Teddy
Owner name: Carl Johnson
There are  0 pets with the same name
```

So I come here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to `printPets` method (adjusted for PEP 8 but still should be clear what each name refers to) (more detailed explanation in the complete code example below):

```py
from collections import Counter

...

    def print_all_pets(self):
        for date, group in groupby(sorted(self.pets_list, key=lambda x: x.entry_date),
                                   key=lambda x: x.entry_date):
            print(f'{"-" * 20} {date} {"-" * 20}')
            counter = Counter()
            for pet in group:
                print(f"Name: {pet.name}")
                print(f"Owner name: {pet.owner_name}")
                counter[pet.name] += 1
            print(f'There are {max(counter.values())} '
                  f'pets with the same name')
```

Complete code example (it also follows PEP 8 which I suggest you follow too); most of the explanation is in the code comments:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from collections import Counter


# using dataclasses because they make it easier
# to create more data driven objects and they can pre-build
# all the comparison methods so that sorting is way easier
# and you can exclude what not to sort
@dataclass(order=True)
class PetShop:
    entry_date: str
    name: field(default_factory=str, compare=False)
    owner_name: field(default_factory=str, compare=False)


class Pets:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pets_list = []

    def add_pet(self, entry_date, name, owner_name):
        entry_pet = PetShop(entry_date, name, owner_name)
        self.pets_list.append(entry_pet)

    def print_all_pets(self):
        # as you can see no key is needed for sorting the `PetShop` instances
        # because dataclass allows to do so, then just group them by their date
        # which seems to require some function, also unpack both values:
        # the date and the group
        for date, group in groupby(sorted(self.pets_list), key=lambda x: x.entry_date):
            # use f-string for formatting and also you can multiply strings
            print(f'{"-" * 20} {date} {"-" * 20}')
            # use counter for counting and update it with the pet name
            # each iteration
            counter = Counter()
            for pet in group:
                print(f"Name: {pet.name}")
                print(f"Owner name: {pet.owner_name}")
                # update the counter
                counter[pet.name] += 1
            # then get the highest count
            print(f'There are {max(counter.values())} '
                  f'pets with the same name')


pets = Pets()

# use a list to make the code less repetitive, this
# allows to loop over the list and add each item to the
# pets.pets_list less repetitively than calling the `add_pet`
# method multiple times manually
pet_shops = [
    ('04/13/2021', 'Pinky', 'David Smith'),
    ('07/10/2020', 'Charlie', 'Joe Davis'),
    ('04/13/2021', 'Pinky', 'Daniel Trincot'),
    ('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'Susan Jones'),
    ('12/22/2018', 'Teddy', 'Carl Johnson'),
    ('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'Richard Campbell'),
    ('04/13/2021', 'Max', 'Bryan Miller'),
    ('07/10/2020', 'Buddy', 'Kathy Brown'),
    ('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'John Brown')
]

for e_date, p_name, o_name in pet_shops:
    pets.add_pet(e_date, p_name, o_name)

pets.print_all_pets()
```

And your original issue was that you checked whether a string was in a list of `PetShop` instances so it would always evaluate to `False` (and the condition even if properly used (actually check if the pet name is in the list of pet names for example), it would just give the count of total pets per groupoing). So for counting as shown above I would suggest using `collections.Counter` since it is way easier than to manually make the algorithm for that.

Useful sources:

- [`dataclasses` library (built-in)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)
- [`collections.Counter` docs (built-in)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [`itertools.groupby` docs (more for the example)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

On PEP 8:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Class methods have one blank line around them.

Answer (score 0):

first group by using entryDate and then by name

```
for i, j in groupby(pet.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
    print(f"-------{i}-----------")
    for item1, item2  in groupby(list(j), key=lambda k: k.name):
        dic = {}
       for k1 in list(item2):
       if k1.name in dic:
            dic[k1.name] = dic[k1.name]+1
       else:
           dic[k1.name] = 1
       print(f"Name: {k1.name}")
       print(f"Owner name: {k1.ownerName}")
       print(dic)
```

it produces the following result

```
-------04/13/2021-----------
Name: Pinky
Owner name: David Smith
Name: Pinky
Owner name: Daniel Trincot
{'Pinky': 2}
Name: Max
Owner name: Bryan Miller
{'Max': 1}
-------07/10/2020-----------
Name: Charlie
Owner name: Joe Davis
{'Charlie': 1}
Name: Kenny
Owner name: Susan Jones
Name: Kenny
Owner name: Richard Campbell
{'Kenny': 2}
Name: Buddy
Owner name: Kathy Brown
{'Buddy': 1}
Name: Kenny
Owner name: John Brown
{'Kenny': 1}
-------12/22/2018-----------
Name: Teddy
Owner name: Carl Johnson
{'Teddy': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see three gotchas in your code above.

1. The groupby creates a generator, this will only have iterable data once.

```
    def printPets(self):
        self.petsList.sort(key=lambda p: p.entryDate)
        counter = 0
        for group in groupby(self.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
            ls = list(group)
            print(f'first {list(ls[1])}')
            print(f'second {list(ls[1])}')
#first [<__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd1001e430>, <__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd504428b0>, <__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd50446d00>]
#second []
```

You are on the right track trying to use list() on group, but you need to unpack date and pets first. Here is a possible fix

```
    def printPets(self):
        self.petsList.sort(key=lambda p: p.entryDate)
        counter = 0
        for date, pets in groupby(self.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
            pet_list = list(pets)
            print(f'first {pet_list}')
            print(f'second {pet_list}')
#first [<__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd1001e430>, <__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd504428b0>, <__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd50446d00>]
#second [<__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd1001e430>, <__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd504428b0>, <__main__.Petshop object at 0x7fcd50446d00>]
```

2. petlist is a list of pets, not a list of pet_names, so the if statement will never be true, we can fix this using the below.

```
    def printPets(self):
        self.petsList.sort(key=lambda p: p.entryDate)
        counter = 0
        for date, pets in groupby(self.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
            pet_list = list(pets)
            pet_names = [p.name for p in pet_list]
            print("---------------", ls[0], '------------------')
            for pet in pet_list:
                print("Name:", pet.name)
                print("Owner name:", pet.ownerName)
                if pet.name in pet_names:
                    counter += 1
            print('There are ',counter,'pets with the same name')
```

3. The count is always equal to the number of pets. You only want to check unseen pets to count for repeated ones, since each pet appears in the pet_list at least once.

```
    def printPets(self):
        self.petsList.sort(key=lambda p: p.entryDate)
        counter = 0
        for agg, vals in groupby(self.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
            _vals = list(vals)
            name_list =[x.name for x in _vals]
            print("---------------", agg, '------------------')
            for i, pet in enumerate(_vals):
                print("Name:", pet.name)
                print("Owner name:", pet.ownerName)
                if pet.name in name_list[:i]:
                    counter += 1
            print('There are ',counter,'pets with the same name')
```

There is also a minor fix I included in (2), preventing the intermediate counts for being printed by unindenting the print statement.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the best way to do this, but here you go. The counter should have to be reset for every group and as @Matiiss said, ls[1] is the instance of the PetShop class, so saving that in variables could be better and accessing its attributes could make it more clear.

```
from itertools import groupby

class Petshop():
    def __init__(self, entryDate, name, ownerName):
        self.entryDate = entryDate
        self.name = name
        self.ownerName = ownerName
        
class Pets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.petsList = []
        
    def addPets(self, entryDate, name, ownerName ):
        entry_pet = Petshop(entryDate, name, ownerName)
        self.petsList.append(entry_pet)
        
    def printPets(self):
        self.petsList.sort(key=lambda p: p.entryDate)
        
        for group in groupby(self.petsList, key=lambda p: p.entryDate):
            ls = list(group)
            data = list(ls[1])
            names= []
            print("--------", ls[0], "--------")
            index = 0
            for pet in list(data):   
                if pet.name in names :
                    repeatedName = pet.name
                index+= 1
                
                print("Name:", pet.name)
                names.append(pet.name)
                print("Owner:", pet.ownerName)
               
                if index == len(data):
                   print("There are", names.count(repeatedName), "pets with the same name")
            names = []
            
pet = Pets()

pet.addPets('04/13/2021','Pinky', 'David Smith')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Charlie', 'Joe Davis')
pet.addPets('04/13/2021','Pinky', 'Daniel Trincot')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'Susan Jones')
pet.addPets('12/22/2018', 'Teddy', 'Carl Johnson')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'Richard Campbell')
pet.addPets('04/13/2021','Max', 'Bryan Miller')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Buddy', 'Kathy Brown')
pet.addPets('07/10/2020', 'Kenny', 'John Brown')
pet.printPets()
```

Here is the output that I got

```
-------- 04/13/2021 --------
Name: Pinky
Owner: David Smith
Name: Pinky
Owner: Daniel Trincot
Name: Max
Owner: Bryan Miller
There are 2 pets with the same name
-------- 07/10/2020 --------
Name: Charlie
Owner: Joe Davis
Name: Kenny
Owner: Susan Jones
Name: Kenny
Owner: Richard Campbell
Name: Buddy
Owner: Kathy Brown
Name: Kenny
Owner: John Brown
There are 3 pets with the same name
-------- 12/22/2018 --------
Name: Teddy
Owner: Carl Johnson
There are 0 pets with the same name
```